# Html-rendering structures and arrays in Go

Tags: go

I render template:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
t.Execute(w, &page{Title: "Title"})
```

Its works well. But what if, for example, I have structure from database?

How can I render it by Go? Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works no differently. `ExecuteTemplate` accepts an `interface{}` so you can pass it anything you'd like.

I typically pass a `map[string]interface{}` like so:

```
// Shorthand
type M map[string]interface{}

...

err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "posts.tmpl", M{
        "posts": &posts,
        "user": &user,
        "errors": []pageErrors,
 }

 // posts.tmpl

 {{ posts.PostTitle }} 
 {{ with user }}
      Hello, {{ Name }}!
      {{ Email }}
 {{ end }}
 ...
```

Hope that clarifies. The [Go docs](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) have a useful example that includes how to use the `html/template` package.

Answer (score 2):

Go templates are made exactly for that. Have a look at a few examples from here:

http://golangtutorials.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/go-templates.html

and here:

http://jan.newmarch.name/golang/template/chapter-template.html

Comment: I was just going to add Jan's article to my answer ;) It really is an excellent resource on `html/template` (and even `text/template`, since they're almost the same thing).